# MySql Query by Hour

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a table which is returned by a query

```
+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+
| userid |  logintime             |  logouttime             | Download(KB) | Upload(KB)   |
+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+
| ma29   |  "2015-07-29 16:25:50" |  "2015-07-29 16:38:17"  |  86.6904     |  25.1328     |
| ma29   |  "2015-07-29 16:38:47" |  "2015-07-29 17:45:41"  |  920.2256    |  16005.5889  |
| ma29   |  "2015-07-29 17:47:32" |  "2015-07-29 17:54:09"  |  18.2939     |  10.9756     |
| ma29   |  "2015-07-29 17:54:38" |  "2015-07-29 17:56:31"  |  0.0000      |  0.0000      |
| ma29   |  "2015-07-29 17:56:39" |  "2015-07-29 18:16:53"  |  78.5596     |  57.5908     |
+--------+------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

How do I calculate a user's active time by the hour between a given time range  as follows :

For Eg: Searching User's Active Time between 2015-07-29 16:00 to 2015-07-30 11:00 by the hour :

```
+---------------+-------------------+
| Hours         | Active Time(secs) |
+---------------+-------------------+
| 2015-07-29 16 | 2020              | 
| 2015-07-29 17 | 3452              | 
| 2015-07-29 18 | 1013              | 
| ............. | ................. |
| ............. | ................. |
| ............. | ................. |
| ............. | ................. |
| 2015-07-30 09 | 0                 | 
| 2015-07-30 10 | 10                | 
+---------------+-------------------+
```

I am stuck. Don't know how to start this solution. Another query or stored procedure ??

Comment: are you looking for sum(seesiontime) where userid='..' and date=...??

Comment: No. It should be like Hour by Hour basis Eg: User logs in at 16:00 and logs out at 17:30. Then Output is 16:00 - (60*60) seconds and 17:00 - (30*60) seconds. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**plan**

1. create `digits_v` to generate sequences
2. cross join 3 times and apply powers of ten to construct `hours` numbers upto 999 ( if this is less than the maximum difference between the inputs, then just extend with another cross-join and power of ten )
3. construct `allhours` using start input and `hours` until end input is reached
4. join `allhours` to session ( s ) using condition :

   ```
   date_add(allhours.hourstart, interval 1 hour) > s.logintime
   and allhours.hourstart < s.logouttime
   ```

   this will take those records that were active in the `allhours` hour.
5. construct clamp_left and clamp_right within the hour interval. dealing with nulls.
6. sum time difference from clamp_left to clamp_right

---

**query**

```
select hourstart, userid, sum(time_to_sec(timediff(clamp_right, clamp_left))) as active
from
(
  select 
  allhours.hourstart,
  s.userid,
  s.logintime,
  s.logouttime,
  case when s.logintime is null or (s.logintime < allhours.hourstart) 
       then allhours.hourstart
       else s.logintime
  end as clamp_left
  ,
  case when s.logouttime is null
       then allhours.hourstart
       when s.logouttime > date_add(allhours.hourstart, interval 1 HOUR)
       then date_add(allhours.hourstart, interval 1 HOUR)
       else s.logouttime
  end as clamp_right
  from
  (
    select date_add(str_to_date('2015-07-29 16:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'), 
                    interval a2.n * 100 + a1.n * 10 + a0.n HOUR) as hourstart
    from digits_v a2
    cross join digits_v a1
    cross join digits_v a0
  ) allhours
  left join sessions s
  on 
  (
    date_add(allhours.hourstart, interval 1 hour) > s.logintime
    and allhours.hourstart < s.logouttime
  )
  where hourstart < str_to_date('2015-07-30 11:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
) q1
group by hourstart, userid
order by hourstart, userid
;
```

**output**

```
+------------------------+--------+--------+
|       hourstart        | userid | active |
+------------------------+--------+--------+
| July, 29 2015 16:00:00 | ma29   |   2020 |
| July, 29 2015 17:00:00 | ma29   |   3452 |
| July, 29 2015 18:00:00 | ma29   |   1013 |
| July, 29 2015 19:00:00 | (null) |      0 |
| July, 29 2015 20:00:00 | (null) |      0 |
| July, 29 2015 21:00:00 | (null) |      0 |
| July, 29 2015 22:00:00 | (null) |      0 |
| July, 29 2015 23:00:00 | (null) |      0 |
| July, 30 2015 00:00:00 | (null) |      0 |
| July, 30 2015 01:00:00 | (null) |      0 |
| July, 30 2015 02:00:00 | (null) |      0 |
| July, 30 2015 03:00:00 | (null) |      0 |
| July, 30 2015 04:00:00 | (null) |      0 |
| July, 30 2015 05:00:00 | (null) |      0 |
| July, 30 2015 06:00:00 | (null) |      0 |
| July, 30 2015 07:00:00 | (null) |      0 |
| July, 30 2015 08:00:00 | (null) |      0 |
| July, 30 2015 09:00:00 | (null) |      0 |
| July, 30 2015 10:00:00 | (null) |      0 |
+------------------------+--------+--------+
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d809e/1)**

Comment: Bingo !.... This is THE Solution. Was Coding in Java to return as POJO to Report Input. But Your answer made it easy. Thankssssssssss AMDixon....

Comment: nw this sort of thing can be handled in either sql or application. but i would say for queries this size that itll be more maintainable in one sql snippet than lots of scattered application objects ( eg POJOs )

Comment: Yes.. I was finding it difficult to construct this Very Complex Query.